# Azure AD Auth against ProtectedWebWebi

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I downloaded the Azure examples for daemon app, and have a bearer token at the end of the debug code. The thing that I'm stuck on is calling the Web API with this token to Authenticate. This is in .NET Core 2.2

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // This is required to be instantiated before the OpenIdConnectOptions starts getting configured.
        // By default, the claims mapping will map claim names in the old format to accommodate older SAML applications.
        // 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' instead of 'roles'
        // This flag ensures that the ClaimsIdentity claims collection will be built from the claims in the token
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

        services.AddProtectWebApiWithMicrosoftIdentityPlatformV2(Configuration);

        services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            //options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
        });

        //// Creating policies that wraps the authorization requirements
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AdminUsers", policy => policy.RequireRole("AdminUsers"));
        });

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(TodoStore.Values);
    }
```

I took the roles out and just made it available to everyone, not sure if I need to put Group authorization on here for it to work. I can't get it to work out of the box. I'm thinking of modifying some of these to make it work. We only need to authenticate, then use their email to get roles base on which application they are in.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-call-api?tabs=dotnet)

> For daemon apps, the web APIs that you call need to be pre-approved.
> There's no incremental consent with daemon apps. (There's no user
> interaction.) The tenant admin needs to provide consent in advance for
> the application and all the API permissions.

and there is a [GitHub sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/ms-identity-daemon/) for daemon application which consume Web Api and if you are trying to verify app roles in the APIs called by a Daemon apps please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles)